# How does a constructor work in a TestNG class inheriting from a parent java class

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

In testng class, I have a constructor with following methods 
super(driver) - this calls parent class and passes driver object 
setup() - this call goes to parent class,where a new driver object is created

Eg code

```
public class LoginTestNG extends ProjectTestBase {

  WebDriver driver;  
  static By locator = By.name("airline");



  public LoginTestNG(WebDriver driver) {
      super(driver);
      System.out.println("I am in constructor");
      setup();

  }  



  @Test(dataProvider = "logn")
  public static void login_with_valid_user_param(String uname, String passwd){  
      LoginActions.submit_login(uname,passwd);      
  }

  @DataProvider(name = "logn")
  public static Object[][] loginData(){

      return new Object[][]{{"test","test"}};
  }

}
```

Parent class code:

```
public class ProjectTestBase{

  public LoginActions loginActions;
    static LoginPage loginPage;
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public ProjectTestBase(WebDriver driver){               
        this.driver=driver;     
    }


  public static void setup(){
      driver = startBrowser("firefox");
      createActions(driver);
      createPages(driver);
      launchURL("http://newtours.demoaut.com/index.php");
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
  }

  public static void createActions(WebDriver driver){
      loginActions = new com.newtours.actions.LoginActions(driver);
  }

  public static void createPages(WebDriver driver){
      loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
  }
}
```

my question is: 
1. This code works fine if i run the test in a java class
2. If I add the test to a testNG class it does not work, I mean, I am getting
null pointer exception because driver object is null. I think the constructor is not getting invoked, I need help to understand if the constructor works differently in a testng class.

Thanks
sk

Answer (score 2):

TestNG doesn't call your constructor with parameter `WebDriver driver` so it's null.

If you want to pass some arguments to your test you can use:

- `@Parameters` http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters
- `@DataProvider` http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders

Or you can init your `WebDriver` in `@BeforeSuite` / `@BeforeClass` etc. methods.

Comment: Thanks Jaroslav for your suggestions, I have already tried the options, but my question was how constructor behaves in a testNG class. Is it a good practice to use constructors or take help of annotations provided by TestNG.

Comment: TestNG basically creates classes using reflection (https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/internal/ClassHelper.java) so it's not good idea to use "simple" constructors because, as you saw, it doesn't work. Instead of it you should use annotations provided by TestNG (like `@BeforeXXX, @DataProvider, @Factory` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

TestNg execute test cases on annotation based, You have two webdriver reference variable one in parent which is initialized when you called setup method on child class, Another webdriver reference variable is in child class which always null value.

Solution: you need to use TestNG beforeclass or BeforeSuite in parent class setup method like below:

```
public class ProjectTestBase {
   public LoginActions loginActions;
   static LoginPage loginPage;
   public static WebDriver driver;

   /*public ProjectTestBase(WebDriver driver) {
       this.driver = driver;
   }*/

   @BeforeClass
   public static void setup() {
       driver = startBrowser("firefox");
       createActions(driver);
       createPages(driver);
       launchURL("http://newtours.demoaut.com/index.php");
       driver.manage().window().maximize();
   }

   public static void createActions(WebDriver driver) {
       loginActions = new com.newtours.actions.LoginActions(driver);
    }

    public static void createPages(WebDriver driver) {
        loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
    }
}
```

Remove constructor from both class:

Run your testng test, now it will solve null pointer exception.

Thanks
Sadik